# OkHttp newBuilder()

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

What does the function [newBuilder()](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html#newBuilder--) exactly does in OkHttp. Does it create an entirely new client or adjusts the existing client as given [here](https://square.github.io/okhttp/3.x/okhttp/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.html). What exactly 'adjusts' means in this case?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It creates a shallow copy, so you can change some configuration while leaving everything else the same.

Comment: Is this also true for other classes e.g., `Request`?

Comment: Yep. `Request.newBuilder()` is initially populated with the state of the original request.

Answer (score 3):

### client.newBuilder()

When you want to reuse a part of current client's configuration , you can use this method to create a new builder and then you can use this new builder to add your new setting such as `cookjar`,etc.